# PHP's move_uploaded_file error: Permission denied on Mac

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I seem to have a problem uploading file to the web server. I've made myself a simple form and have a PHP file to control the uploading but every time I run the code, I get an error. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['upload']['error'];

if ($error = 0) {
   move_uploaded_file($temp, "images/" . $name);
   echo 'Success';
} else {
   die ('$error');
}
?>
```

and this is the error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/macbook.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/doc/ch07/upload_check.php on line 7

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phpuMC0td' to 'images/macbook.jpg' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/doc/ch07/upload_check.php on line 7
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just make sure that directory `images` does exist

Comment: set `'images/'` folder permission to 777

Comment: How could you set permission to 777 @Cattla?

Comment: images directory does exist @Ghost

Comment: try this http://computgozez.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-set-file-permissions-in-mac-os-x.html

Answer (score 0):

error assign vs evaluate
`if ($error = 0)` should be `if ($error == 0)`

name is from basename. also declare the target before.

```
$target_path_file = 'images/' .basename($_FILES['upload']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($temp, $target_path_file);
```

Comment: This works but I need to change 'wheel' and 'everyone' in the permission section to all 'Read & Write'. Is that safe for security reasons?

Comment: it's a mac setting. i don't have any idea about it, but this artile might. have a look [link to article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1485710)